# Pop Up jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, browser, popup, contact-form

I need pop up jquery plugin for all content, images, contact form and must be supported for all browsers (ie7+, chrome, firefox, safari)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use google https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=pop%20up%20jquery%20plugin

Answer (score 1):

Check it out!
Hope it's ok :)
http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/popup/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2013/01/jquery-popup-window-tutorial-plugins.html
http://www.designyourway.net/drb/a-collection-of-useful-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes-31-plugins/
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/04/8-jquery-popup-window-plugin-examples.html

And also

https://www.google.com/search?q=popup+window+jquery+cross+browser&oq=popup+window+jquery+cross+browser&aqs=chrome..69i57.8747j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fp=8a1d521228289b&q=popup+jquery+plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Magnific Popup , and hope it will help you.

`http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/`

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer JQueryUI dialog plug-in because it is of the same foundation of JQuery and they have very detailed API documentations.

Have a look at their demo page : http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

here are few plugins for the above mentioned purpose!
http://fancybox.net/

http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/